# Swift- Problem making multiple GET requests with Alamofire

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, api, alamofire

I am having issues loading data from a GET request with Alamofire in swift to load items into a UITableView.

I have 2 methods `fetchAllBeerOrders` and `fetchAllCocktailOrders` which both are working properly and fetching the correct items. The issue I am having is in the `viewWillAppear` method where I call both of these fetch methods and reload the tableView. In the order I have it only the items from the `fetchAllCocktailOrders` method are loading in the tableView and I have verified by switching the order and getting the items loaded from `fetchAllBeerOrders`.

```swift
class DrinkOrdersTableViewController: UITableViewController { 
    var orders: [Order] = [] 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Current Orders"

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        fetchAllBeerOrders { orders in
            self.orders = orders!
            //print("Beer fetch: ", self.orders)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        fetchAllCocktailOrders { orders in
            self.orders = orders!
            //print("Cocktail fetch: ", self.orders)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    private func fetchAllCocktailOrders(completion: @escaping([Order]?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request("http://127.0.0.1:4000/orders", method: .get)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.isSuccess else { return completion(nil) }
                guard let rawInventory = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]?] else { return completion(nil) }
                let currentOrders = rawInventory.compactMap { ordersDict -> Order? in
                    guard let orderId = ordersDict!["id"] as? String,
                        let orderStatus = ordersDict!["status"] as? String,
                        var pizza = ordersDict!["cocktail"] as? [String: Any] else { return nil }
                    pizza["image"] = UIImage(named: pizza["image"] as! String)

                    return Order(
                        id: orderId,
                        pizza: Pizza(data: pizza),
                        status: OrderStatus(rawValue: orderStatus)!
                    )

                }
                completion(currentOrders)
        }

    }

    private func fetchAllBeerOrders(completion: @escaping([Order]?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request("http://127.0.0.1:4000/orders", method: .get)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.isSuccess else { return completion(nil) }
                guard let rawInventory = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]?] else { return completion(nil) }
                let currentOrders = rawInventory.compactMap { ordersDict -> Order? in
                    guard let orderId = ordersDict!["id"] as? String,
                        let orderStatus = ordersDict!["status"] as? String,
                        var pizza = ordersDict!["pizza"] as? [String: Any] else { return nil }
                    pizza["image"] = UIImage(named: pizza["image"] as! String)

                    return Order(
                        id: orderId,
                        pizza: Pizza(data: pizza),
                        status: OrderStatus(rawValue: orderStatus)!
                    )

                }
                completion(currentOrders)
        }
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Debugging ROWS", orders.count)
        return orders.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "order", for: indexPath)
        let order = orders[indexPath.row]        
        cell.textLabel?.text = order.pizza.name
        cell.imageView?.image = order.pizza.image
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(order.pizza.amount) - \(order.status.rawValue)"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "orderSegue", sender: orders[indexPath.row] as Order)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "orderSegue" {
            guard let vc = segue.destination as? OrderViewController else { return }
            vc.order = sender as? Order
        }
    }
}
```

Im not sure if I need to combine the GET requests into a single request or if my logic on the approach is wrong but I need the tableView to load orders from both `fetchAllBeerOrders` and `fetchAllCocktailOrders`. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Like Levi Yonder says, it is indeed a problem with the results of your second request replacing the `order`, but his provided answer is not optimal.

You have to keep in mind that network requests are asynchronous. This means `fetchAllCocktailOrders` can finish **before** the `fetchAllBeerOrders` request is completed. In that case the same problem would occur:

1. Requests fire at the same time
2. `fetchAllCocktailOrders` completes first, appends the data to orders
3. `fetchAllBeerOrders` completes, replaces current batch of data with result of this request.

Solution:

```
fetchAllBeerOrders { orders in
    self.orders.append(orders)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

fetchAllCocktailOrders { orders in
    self.orders.append(orders)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I have indeed tried this method before your comment :/ . I thought I could just append the contents of orders in each call to fetchAll...Orders but I am still getting the error ```Cannot convert value of type '[Order]' to expected argument type 'Order'``` on both append lines (```self.orders.append(orders!)```)

Comment: I have been messing with this issue all day, do you know if there is another good way to append to an array with this type of data?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having this issue is that `fetchAllCocktailOrders` replaces everything in `orders` that the `fetchAllBeerOrders` initially had fetched, versus appending to.

So `viewWillAppear` is calling `fetchAllBeerOrders`, which populates `orders`, and then `fetchAllCocktailOrders` is replacing everything in `orders` instead of appending to everything in `orders`.

To fix this, when you call the `fetchAllCocktailOrders`, append `orders` with the contents of what is being returned by the function, instead of replacing:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        fetchAllBeerOrders { beerOrders in
            self.orders = beerOrders!
            //print("Beer fetch: ", self.orders)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        fetchAllCocktailOrders { coctailOrders in
          self.orders.append(coctailOrders)
            //print("Cocktail fetch: ", self.orders)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have tried this approach but presented with an expected argument type of ```Order```. As shown: (https://i.imgur.com/v1uaurL.png). I believe this is because it is expecting an array of type ```orders```. I think appending the data is on the right track but im sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

To achieve my goal of loading data from both GET requests I needed to append the data to the orders array with the `.append(contentsOf: orders!)` method instead of with `self.orders = orders!`. In the viewWillAppear method the second call to `fetchCocktailOrders` will always overwrite the contents from the first call to `fetchBeerOrders`. Clearly I am a swift rookie!

```swift
        fetchAllBeerOrders { orders in
            //self.orders.append(orders)
            self.orders.append(contentsOf: orders!)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        fetchAllCocktailOrders { orders in
            //self.orders.append(orders)
            self.orders.append(contentsOf: orders!)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

This is the correct code.